# Storing and retrieving historical data of user's learning progress

Tags: php, mysql

Preface: I'm developing an application that quizzes users on multiple topics. I wish to keep a history of their progress and be able to easily present the user with a daily,weekly and monthly view of their progress on a per topic basis.

The initial design for my table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_topics` (
  `ProgressID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `UserID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `TopicID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Level` decimal(3,1) NOT NULL,
  `TotalCorrect` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `QuestionsAsked` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY (`ProgressID`)
 )
```

Am I going along the right lines/ how can I retrieve the data I need to provide a presentable history?

**Edit:**

I'd want to display a graph with time as a scale and % correct, this would be done when a user clicks to view their monthly/weekly progress for their topics. I would like the load time between viewing weekly/ monthly data per topic pretty transparent.

Should the data be retrieved in a single call(just select the rows  with from date x until now) then  then leave it up to the individual client to organise the data into days/months etc then present the data?

Comment: What kind of data you want to retrieve? As for presentable history that's up to you. For the history logging, just create a new row per time you save the users' statistics. Once you have this data logged, for historical history queries, do a query such as `WHERE UserID = '132' AND DateTime between now() - interval 7 day and now()` - which of course you need to expand on depending on what you are needing.

Comment: There should be another table with progressID being the foreign key I think

Comment: @paabobo why would that be needed?

Comment: progressID represents the id for that table, maybe that would have been more clear if I'd have had it auto increment in the example.

Comment: having a primary key auto_increment is always a good idea, this way you don't need to worry about uniqueness. using the progressID as foreign key in another table only makes sense if you want to associate data with the record, that doesn't fit in the user_topics table, for example because of a one-to-many relationship, or a many-to-many relationship, but in that case, you'd need 2 extra tables, one for the relationships, and one for the other type of data.

Comment: Yeah, such as userID and topicID. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use date_between to query for all progress records betweentwo dates with something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 'user_topics' WHERE 'DateTime' between '2008-12-23' AND '2008-12-25';
```

[here is the mysql documentation for 'between ... and ...'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

So now, using some graphing tools, you could get all the progress for the last day/week/month/year and present their progress.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was aware of being able to query between dates I guess I'm more confused about how big of a role the data access should play. For example do I just execute one big call retrieving the data I need to present the weekly and monthly views?

Comment: I would get one query for the past year, and then store the info in memcache, or some other caching framework, so that you don't need to keep doing the query. You could make the cached data expire in 5 minutes, this way, the user has a smooth experience while browsing through their results, I guess they don't need to be updated and displayed with an interval smaller then 5 minutes.